# Visual C++ A queue of Mat images elements: how?

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I try to do a queue of Mat images elements, but Visual C++ give me an error about "tipe" of queue.

I want to have an concurrent queue of OpenCV Mat images for use it with multiple threads.

How can I do this?

This is the code of the queue give me error (created about an example see in this forum):

```
template<data Mat>
 class coda_concorr
  {
  private:
std::queue<Mat> la_coda;
HANDLE mutex;
public:
void push(Mat const& data)
{
    WaitForSingleObject(mutex,INFINITE):
    la_coda.push(data);
    RelaseMutex(mutex);
}
bool vuota() const
{
    WaitForSingleObject(mutex,INFINITE);
    return la_coda.empty();
    ReleaseMutex(mutex);
}

bool try_pop(Mat& popped)
{
    WaitForSingleObject(mutex,INFINITE);
    if (la_coda.empty())
    {
        return false;
    }
    popped = la_coda.front();
    la_coda.pop();
    return true;
}

void aspetta_per_pop(Mat& popped)
{
    WaitForSingleObject(mutex,INFINITE);
    while (la_coda.empty())
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(mutex,INFINITE);
    }
    popped=la_coda.front();
    la_coda.pop();
}
};
```

I use Visual Studio 2010 and OpenCV 2.4.4

Comment: Can you post the actual error you get?

Comment: error C2061: errore di sintassi: identificatore 'data'
'coda_concorr': elenco dei parametri di modello mancante o non valido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is invalid template syntax:

```
template<data Mat>
class coda_concorr { .... };
```

You are not using any template parameters in your class, so you could make it a non-template. But it would make more sense to make it a template, and replace `Mat` by the template parameter.

```
template<typename T>
class coda_concorr
{
 private:
  std::queue<T> la_coda;
  ....
 public:
  void push(T const& data) { .... }
};
```

then, you can instantiate the template for a `cv::Mat`:

```
coda_concorr<cv::Mat> matQueue;
```

or a different type, this being the point of making the class a template in the first place:

```
coda_concorr<int> intQueue;
coda_concorr<std::string> stringQueue;
```

Comment: And where I declare that is a "Mat" queue?

Comment: @Domenico when you instantiate a `coda_concorr`. Read about templates.

Comment: I instantiate queue like you indicate. When I try to push on it a Mat variables, give error C2676. Why?

Comment: I can't have competition between two threads with this queue. If use the queue with only one thread, works. If I use two threads, the problem of push into queue it's that I get.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I'd use a third-party library for a concurrent queue, because writing efficient thread-safe code is considered hard. I can recommend the [PPL library from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504906.aspx#queue) or the [TBB library from Intel](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/tbb_sa/help/index.htm#reference/reference.htm).